# Prestashop 1.6: query to add product weight to all items

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to add weight to all products in my prestashop 1.6.1.10. I have updated the product table (in my case ps16_product) but it seems it doesn't work. Here goes the query:

```
update ps16_product set weight='0.3' where id_category_default=152;
```

When I go to the prestashop backoffice I can see the it doesn't effect the product weight. It is still empty. Most likely this column - weight in ps16_product table is left for back compatibility with the older versions of presta.

I have tested adding product weight through the backend and I found in the database dump that the weight is stored in ps16_feature_value_lang. Something like this:

```
| id_feature_value | id_lang | value      |

|               36 |       1 | 0.4359876  |
```

Any idea what query i have to use to add/update product weight?

Answer (score 0):

the feature values and product weight are different things in prestashop. The weight in product talbe is used for shipping calculations. As the weight in features is to display in front office. Of course, some themes can use the weight in product table to display in front office.
Also, in back office, the weight in features, of course shows in the features tab, as the weight used for shipping calculations is set in the shipping tabs. and they can be different. You may want to display the real weight of the product but use a different one for shipping (due to packaging for example).

I would recommend setting only one weight, in shipping, and change the theme to display it, if it doesn't already. If you want to set the feature value, it's a more complicated query, because it would need to had to the feature_value and to the feature_product tables with the correct id_product, id_feature, and id_feature_value.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully add a weight value to all products inside a category using a simple sql query:

```
UPDATE ps_product SET weight=1 WHERE id_category_default=581
```

I hope this information is helpful for you.